# Sum grouped elements in XSL 1.0

Tags: xslt, sum, distinct, grouping

XSL is driving me nuts and I hope someone can help me with this one. The code is ready for copy paste.

I am doing a group by in XSL 1.0 and I wish to make sum on all grouped 'Amount' elements.

My data looks like this.

```
<CustInvoiceTable class="entity">
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.05</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000088</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.07</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000088</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.16</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000091</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.22</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000091</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>1.33</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000098</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>1.82</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000098</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.01</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000086</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.01</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000086</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.05</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000062</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>2</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.06</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000062</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>2</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.02</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000111</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.02</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000111</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.06</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000089</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.08</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000089</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>1.96</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000092</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>2.69</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000092</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.07</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000101</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.10</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000101</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.07</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000102</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.10</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000102</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>6.69</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000083</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>7.96</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000083</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.15</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000067</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>0.21</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000067</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>1</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>96.00</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000125</ItemId>
        <McsCmBilProductItem class="entity">
            <CgiBundleLines>0</CgiBundleLines>
        </McsCmBilProductItem>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>-88.00</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000069</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>-0.66</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000083</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>-0.22</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000092</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>
    <McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine class="entity">
        <Amount>-0.55</Amount>
        <ItemId>ITM-0000098</ItemId>
    </McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine>

</CustInvoiceTable>
```

And the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="Lines-by-ItemId" match="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine" use="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine/ItemId" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <root>

            <xsl:for-each select="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[count(. | key('Lines-by-ItemId', ItemId)[1]) = 1][McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1][not(ItemId = preceding-sibling::McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine/ItemId)]">
                <xsl:sort select="ItemId" />
                <GroupInvoiceLine>
                    <ItemId><xsl:value-of select="ItemId" /></ItemId>
                    <SumAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(Amount)"/></SumAmount> <!-- This does not work -->
                </GroupInvoiceLine>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </root>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:
Say that we group on "ITM-0000088" I expect the result to be 0.12. Currently it just grabs the first record.

If we group on "ITM-0000083" I would expect the sum to be 6.69 + 7.96 = 14.65 and NOT 6.69 + 7.96 + -0.66 = 13.99 since the last 'McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine' with 'ItemId = ITM-0000083' does not have 'CgiBundleLines = 1' in its 'McsCmBilProductItem'.

Comment: You have a lot of code here. Please post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Yes - I will reduce the amount of data next time around. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the key as `<xsl:key name="Lines-by-ItemId" match="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine" use="ItemId" />`, as the `use` attribute value is computed relative to the matched node.

Then to first see how to use the key and Muenchian grouping, use

```
        <xsl:for-each select="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[count(. | key('Lines-by-ItemId', ItemId)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="ItemId" />
            <GroupInvoiceLine>
                <ItemId><xsl:value-of select="ItemId" /></ItemId>
                <SumAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Lines-by-ItemId', ItemId)/Amount)"/></SumAmount> 
            </GroupInvoiceLine>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

As for the other condition, consider to include it inside the key pattern:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="Lines-by-ItemId" match="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1]" use="ItemId" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <root>

            <xsl:for-each select="CustInvoiceTable/McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine[McsCmBilProductItem/CgiBundleLines = 1][count(. | key('Lines-by-ItemId', ItemId)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="ItemId" />
                <GroupInvoiceLine>
                    <ItemId><xsl:value-of select="ItemId" /></ItemId>
                    <SumAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Lines-by-ItemId', ItemId)/Amount)"/></SumAmount> 
                </GroupInvoiceLine>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </root>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Brilliant job again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, your key should be defined as:

```
<xsl:key name="Lines-by-ItemId" match="McsCmBilCalcInvoiceLine" use="ItemId" />
```

Then change:

```
<SumAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(Amount)"/></SumAmount>
```

to:

```
<SumAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Lines-by-ItemId',ItemId)/Amount)"/></SumAmount>
```

Comment: This does not produce the wanted result. It does not take into consideration that only lines with 'CgiBundleLines = 1' should be grouped. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @Lange You can add the predicate to the group being summed. (It's not a good strategy to ask about more than one thing at the same time).

Comment: Thank you Michael. You are probably right. I will refrain from this in the future.